# Requiriments to run macOS with iOS emulator on PC (Windows or Linux)

Tags: macos, flutter, virtual-machine, hardware

I am a Flutter developer but I don't have a MacBook.
My idea is run in VirtualBox the macOS and run iOS emulator inside him.

How much memory ram is recommended to this virtual machine?
What is the minimum recommended processor to run this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check in with the https://superuser.com/ community on this one. You might find it’s a common question. This forum is for programming questions not general hardware/software.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is forbidden by Apple's license.  You must have Apple hardware to run macos (even virtually).